# How to insert values into table based off values of another table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

So in SQL, I have a table albums that has (album_id, album_name, year)
I also have a table songs that has (song_id, song_name, album_name).

I used an alter table statement to add a column to songs called album_id

For each song that belongs to an album, I want to add its respective album_id to that row

I'm not sure how to do this. I've done

```
UPDATE songs
SET songs.album_id = (select albums.album_id FROM albums WHERE songs.album_name = albums.album_name);
```

However that subquery returns more than one row and gives me an error. I've also tried adding `distinct` in the subquery and adding a `group by` albums.album_id in the subquery.

There are multiple songs in the songs table that belong to the same album.
Each album only appears once in the album table.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. LIkely, you have several albums that share the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html) it to one if it is always the same album_id

```
UPDATE songs
SET songs.album_id = (select albums.album_id 
                      FROM albums 
                      WHERE songs.album_name = albums.album_name 
                      LIMIT 1);
```

A grouup by makes only then sense if you wnat to add more information to a description field

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem.  Albums have duplicate names.  You can find them in the data:

```
select a.album_name, count(*)
from albums a
group by a.album_name
having count(*) > 1;
```

Now, you might have accidental duplicates in the data -- the same album appearing more than once.  If so, fix `albums` by removing the duplicates.

Or, you might have *bona fide* different albums with the same name (and presumably different artists).  In that case, you'll need to figure out which belongs to a given user.

You can get started assigning the singletons:

```
UPDATE songs s JOIN
       (SELECT album_name, COUNT(*) as cnt, MIN(album_id) as album_id
        FROM albums a
        GROUP BY album_name
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1   -- safe, there is only one
       ) a
       ON s.album_name = a.album_name
    SET s.album_id = a.album_id;
```

Apparently, this has been discussed on music sites such as this [one](https://forums.stevehoffman.tv/threads/same-name-completely-different-albums.762224/page-7) and this [one](https://pitchfork.com/thepitch/6-great-albums-named-after-other-great-albums/).